# How to absolute position :before pseudo element of child relative to parent?

Tags: html, css

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cassln/qdgp7dwh/).

I have two div elements.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS code for that.

```css
.parent {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #080;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #008;
  right: -10px;
  top: 30px;
}

.child:before {
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #008;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  top: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

How to position `.child:before` related to `.parent` without JS. I know solution with `.parent:before`, but it is not good for me.

Comment: While the `.child` div has a position value of anything other than `static` this is not possible with CSS. It's not clear what you are trying to do or why.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am trying to center `.child:before` relative to parent. Without using `parent:before`.

Comment: Yes...but why? What's wrong with `.parent:before`? Anyway, as I said, this not possible with CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D As you see, blue triangle (.child:before) is a part of .child semantically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

I think you will find this more robust and scalable.

```css
.parent {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #080;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #008;
  left: 50%;
  /* note 50% */
  top: 30px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  /* 2x your arrow size */
}
.child:before {
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #008;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  top: -10px;
  /* your border size */
  margin-left: 10px;
  /* your border-size */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cassln/qdgp7dwh/3/) how is look like what I need. But it uses `.parent:before`, I need same thing with  `.child:before`. But perhaps this is not possible.

Comment: Updated...it's just a matter of adjusting the margins.

Comment: As I say in sibling answer, both elements can have any width.

Comment: Yes, but the margin is only related to the **arrow** width...everything else wil  align regardless of width of the elements. - See? - https://jsfiddle.net/5r0xzduh/

Comment: Yes, now I see, my mistake :) I think, this is solution.

Comment: But change top property of child to 30px, please. This is for preventing overlay.

Answer (score 4):

You can only position an element `absolute`ly in relation to the closest parent that is itself positioned. In your case, that's `.child`.

If `.child` and `.child:before` are not related in your layout, why not put `.child:before` in the parent element, either as `.parent:before`, or as its own element?

Alternatively, if your elements both have fixed widths as in your example, just give the pseudo-element a fixed pixel position as well. [Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/qdgp7dwh/1/).

Comment: No, both elements can be any width. Yes, `parent:before` will work. But as you see, blue triangle (`.child:before`) is a part of `.child` semantically.